# stdout not flushed with Jupyter + Python + threading

Tags: python, ipython, python-multithreading, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've got a Jupyter notebook where I've got a cell which is roughly:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import subprocess as sp

def slow_command(arg):
    res = sp.check_output(["slow_command", arg])
    print "Done:", arg
    return res

results = ThreadPool(4).map(slow_command, args)
```

But when I run the cell, there is a long delay and then all of the output is printed at once:

```
 *60 second delay*
 Done: 1
 Done: 2
 Done: 3
 ... etc ...
```

Instead of the output being printed as it comes in:

```
*5 second delay*
Done: 1
*5 second delay*
Done: 2
... etc ...
```

When I replace the `ThreadPool(4).map(…)` with a regular `map(…)` the output is displayed as expected.

What's going on here? Is there any way I can force the output to be displayed as it comes in when I'm using the ThreadPool?

I've tried adding a `sys.stdout.flush()` and that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: If you haven't already, can you try with ipython & ipykernel from master? There were some changes recently in how output from background threads works.